# Is there a full list of hotkeys/shortcuts for Invision Studio yet?

Tags: shortcuts, invision-studio

I was wondering if there was already a complete list of all the key bindings for Invision Studio? I noticed some unintuitive bindings such as the use of Backspace as Delete. That got me wondering what else I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a software called [Cheatsheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com) (mac only) that can be used to get a list of shortcuts when Invision Studio is open. Here is the list:

[image: Got it, using Cheatsheet]]